# Добавить поле в словарь

Tags: python, словари

Никак не могу найти способ как добавить еще одно поле к словарю который имеет вид

```
data = {
        1 : {'name' : 'h1', 'ip' : '10.0.0.1', 'netmask':'01:00:00:00:00:01'},
        2 : {'name' : 'h2', 'ip' : '10.0.0.2', 'netmask':'01:00:00:00:00:02'},
        3 : {'name' : 'h3', 'ip' : '10.0.0.3', 'netmask':'01:00:00:00:00:03'},
        4 : {'name' : 'h4', 'ip' : '10.0.0.4', 'netmask':'01:00:00:00:00:04'},
        5 : {'name' : 'h5', 'ip' : '10.0.0.5', 'netmask':'01:00:00:00:00:05'},
    }
```

поле которое хочу добавить:

```
6 : {'name' : 'h6', 'ip' : '10.0.0.6', 'netmask':'01:00:00:00:00:06'}
```

Comment: как должен выглядеть словарь `data` __после__ добавления?

Comment: data[6] = {...}

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Код:***

```
data = {
    1: {'name': 'h1', 'ip': '10.0.0.1', 'netmask': '01:00:00:00:00:01'},
    2: {'name': 'h2', 'ip': '10.0.0.2', 'netmask': '01:00:00:00:00:02'},
    3: {'name': 'h3', 'ip': '10.0.0.3', 'netmask': '01:00:00:00:00:03'},
    4: {'name': 'h4', 'ip': '10.0.0.4', 'netmask': '01:00:00:00:00:04'},
    5: {'name': 'h5', 'ip': '10.0.0.5', 'netmask': '01:00:00:00:00:05'},
}

data[6] = {'name': 'h6', 'ip': '10.0.0.6', 'netmask': '01:00:00:00:00:06'}
print(data)
```

***stdout:***

```html
{1: {'name': 'h1', 'ip': '10.0.0.1', 'netmask': '01:00:00:00:00:01'}, 2: {'name': 'h2', 'ip': '10.0.0.2', 'netmask': '01:00:00:00:00:02'}, 3: {'name': 'h3', 'ip': '10.0.0.3', 'netmask': '01:00:00:00:00:03'}, 4: {'name': 'h4', 'ip': '10.0.0.4', 'netmask': '01:00:00:00:00:04'}, 5: {'name': 'h5', 'ip': '10.0.0.5', 'netmask': '01:00:00:00:00:05'}, 6: {'name': 'h6', 'ip': '10.0.0.6', 'netmask': '01:00:00:00:00:06'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Просто присвойте нужное значение следующему элементу словаря так, как будто он уже существует. Элемент будет автоматически создан.

`data[6] = {'name' : 'h6', 'ip' : '10.0.0.6', 'netmask':'01:00:00:00:00:06'}`